# Keyword Search and exporting to output doc in .txt file in Python

Tags: python, string, export

I'm trying to write a python function that reads each individual line of a text file and searches for a keyword: if the keyword is in the line I'm trying to make export the line into a new text document. This would essentially create a way to filter lines of text. Here is what I have so far:

```
#trying to filter and print a line that contains a keyword in a csv or txt 

file
import subprocess
import csv

def findandsearch(word):
    textfile=open('textHCPC17_CONTR_ANWEB.txt', 'r+')
    #openign the selected text file
    outputfile=input('CMSOUTPUT.txt')
    #classifying an ouput file
    word=s'education' #designating a keyword
    for line in textfile:
        textfile.readline()
        if word in textfile: #creating if clause
            print('this is a match') #printing that this is match 
            outputfile.write(word) #I want to write the selected line of the text in the output file
            textfile.close() #closing the original file
            print(word) #I want to print the results
            return #ending function
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am not running into syntax error but my output file is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop should look something like this:

```
for line in textfile:
    if word in line:
        print('blahblah')
        outputfile.write(line)
        textfile.close()
        print(line)
        return
```

In your if clause you have comparison between string and file object and it even sounds weird :-S

In python documentation this solution is explained even better: [python doc - input and output](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Oh, okay, this makes sense. Thanks for the help!